# Web view flicker/blinks while scrolling

Tags: android, webview

I am working on hybrid application,  there are HTML5 files which i bundled within application. I need to play video on some HTML pages for that i used  `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` `permission` in manifest file.

But when i scroll webview it flicker/blinks the view.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android web view Rendering Engine makes flickering usually. U can use some javascript mobile frameworks like JQMobi, Enyo js, JQuery Easing JS to solve this issue.

But what basically i experimented is html browser rendering always flickering in my case.

Comment: Thanks Coder Decoder Encoder i will try with the frameworks you suggested.

Answer (score 14):

I've added:

```
android:layerType="software"
```

to WebView, and it magically solved the problem.

Of course, left out hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the **android:hardwareAccelerated="true"** is the root of the problem. If you really need it, you can solve this issue by calling:

```
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

It requires **API level 11**, so you can wrap it in a method like this:

```
@TargetApi(11)
protected void configureLayerType(WebView webView) {
    webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```