# Strange webview black blinking when scrolling

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading the data from a String, and on the first time when I scroll down the webview blinks couple of times.

Here is my code where I load the data:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, message.getmContent(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And the xml:

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/message_title"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
         />
```

Comment: had you put your web view inside scroll view ? If yes try with removing scroll view.

Comment: try android:focus=false

Comment: then set android:scrollingCache="false"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's also possible to set `software` layer type in xml file and it works fine for me.

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Comment: That's the only solution that worked for me with no drawbacks.

Answer (score 34):

The solution is adding:

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

Comment: webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH); is deprecated in API level 18.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23896233/684582

Comment: LayerType software causes a blank webview for me. Best solution I could find was using setBackgroundColor() with a Color object (important, not an int).

Comment: *setRenderPriority()* method was deprecated in API level 18.
It is not recommended to adjust thread priorities, and this will not be supported in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

After resolving with the above solution, My WebView autoFocused on scroll down.
I resolved the flicker and auto-scroll by:

```
webView.setFocusable(false);
webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To load Data from cache

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webview.loadUrl(Your URL To Load);
```

Comment: While using LOAD_NO_CACHE i am getting little bit delay to load and when we use this is listView that everytime recreate the view is not working well to avoid blinking, so i used LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK this to solve the issue.. i too had same blink issue in webview which is used in listview

Comment: Have you tried using adding android:cacheColorHint="@null"
to the listview?

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to set android:minHeight in xml file and it works fine for me.

```
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:minHeight="200dp"/>
```